# How to search values in multiple csv and create new csv with result in python?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have 5 CSV files with multiple columns and one more csv file with list of ID's.
i have to search ID's across all 5 CSV files and create a new CSV file with results like if value present mark 1 if not mark 0.

for example :

**1.csv**

ID| NAME |ORG
1 | A    |B
2 | C    |D
7 | X    |Y

**2.csv**

ID |NAME |ORG
3  |E    |F
4  |G    |H
7  |V    |U

**id.csv**

ID 
1
2
3
4
7

now result.csv should look like.

**result.csv**

ID | 1.csv |2.csv
1  | 1      |0
2  | 1      |0
3  | 0      |1
4  | 0      |1
7  | 1      |1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a simple implementation with `pandas` and `glob`.

```py
import glob
import pandas as pd

csv_files = glob.glob('[0-9].csv')
id_file = pd.read_csv('id.csv', sep='|', index_col=0)
res = pd.DataFrame(0, index=id_file.index, columns=csv_files)

for f in csv_files:
    tmp = pd.read_csv(f, sep='|', index_col=0)
    res.loc[id_file.index.isin(tmp.index), f] = 1

res.to_csv('result.csv', sep='|')
```

Comment: this is not giving the desired result. it's not marking value to 1.

Comment: it works as expected. Is your csv seprated by `,` or `|`?

Comment: My CSV is separated by **,**

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried with seperator | as shown in above example. But still getting 0 in all columns.

Comment: I've updated the script, should work now @sujitpatel

Comment: now it's working awesome. thank you very much for the help. just one more thing how can i change header name in result.csv.
Thanks again for the help @matq007

Comment: for example in result.csv -id should be cust_id , 1.csv type1 and 2.csv type2. 
i tried "res.rename(columns={'id': 'cust_id', '1.csv': 'type1', '2.csv' : 'type2'}, inplace=True)"
but it's not changing id to cust_id rest is changing.

Comment: you can just simply do `res.columns = ['cust_id', 'type1', 'type2']` before the last line